# How to secure different ports on IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I have a VPS on which Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10 is installed. I have deployed both front-end (Angular-based) and back-end (.Net API based) projects on different ports of the IIS. Angular is hosted on default port (80) and back-end project is hosted on port, say 8031.

Now, in order to apply SSL, I have used *CertifyTheWeb* utility, which is fairly easy. It has automatically applied SSL certificate on the default, front-end project. Now I can access *https://example.com*. But since the API endpoints of my front-end code point to http://example.com:8031, I am getting mixed content errors. I am not sure how to secure the port 8031 using *CertifyTheWeb*. It doesn't accept the domain URL with a port.

How can I secure a specific port, or is there anything else that I can try here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using sub-domain. Instead of binding my API project with a port, I bound it with api.example.com, and created a certificate for the same domain in *CertifyTheWeb*. It's working fine now.